# Problem with Wp_query Search (S) parameter searching a string with separated words

Tags: wordpress

I'm using 's' parameter to generate Wp_query to search a particular string into content.

My problem is when this string have a white space.

My $args conf:

```
 $argsPaged = array(
            // Get the "resources_network" post type.
            'post_type' => 'resources_network',
            'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
            'paged' => $start,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'rnet_category', 
                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                    'terms'    =>  array( $categoryid )
                )
             ),
            's' => esc_attr($texttosearch)
        );

$wpq = new WP_Query( $argsPaged );
```

For example, when $texttosearch = "E-LEARNING 6" , query result is:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (72) ) AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%E-LEARNING%') OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%E-LEARNING%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%E-LEARNING%')) AND ((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%6%') OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%6%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%6%'))) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'resources_network' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY (CASE WHEN wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%E-LEARNING 6%' THEN 1 WHEN wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%E-LEARNING%' AND wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%6%' THEN 2 WHEN wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%E-LEARNING%' OR wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%6%' THEN 3 WHEN wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%E-LEARNING 6%' THEN 4 WHEN wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%E-LEARNING 6%' THEN 5 ELSE 6 END), wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 3
```

I replaced genered strings like this "{5a92e13925a303d097056a5017e22dfb76290b661a9b5cf9d34f0c78e887b4d4}" for "%" .

Problem is it separate  "E-LEARNING" from "6" when it search into title and i don't know why.

Some configuration parameters to fix this? I can't find solution anywhere

Thank you

Comment: are you trying to search by title?

Comment: I need to search by title and content to show all identified posts. If i don't specify any field it's searching into post_content, title and excerpt. I want this but i have this weird problem.